# EJBAccessException within @Schedule method in JBoss 6

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

We are filling a map using remote method EJB from a client. The application is using timer to work on data from this map.

When security-domain is activated using LDAP, the client is able to call remote method using LDAP authentication but `javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: Invalid User` is thrown by timer timeout. The method annotated `@javax.ejb.Schedule` attempt to call to local EJB method, and authentication failed.

I have read lots of threads about this configuration: The most revelant seems to be [Giving security priviliege to a scheduler in Java EE 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14683914/giving-security-priviliege-to-a-scheduler-in-java-ee-6), but the annotation `@RunAs` on the timer seems to have no impact.

I have tried different mix between jboss-app/security-domain and `@org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.SecurityDomain` annotation without success.

Does someone have any experience using timer with LDAP authentication ?

Comment: I have found a workaround using `<module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity">user</module-option>` within login-config.xml, but there is no more check with LDAP regardless of the user.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when principal is not propagate when you use **@RunAs/@RunAsPrincipal**.

To resolve this issue you must change the configuration in your $`JBOSS_HOME/server/<instance>/deploy/ejb3-interceptors-aop.xml` adding:

```xml
<interceptor-ref name="org.jboss.ejb3.security.RunAsSecurityInterceptorFactory"/>
```

in the `StatelessBeanTimeoutMethodStack`

The `ejb3-interceptors-aop.xml` (line 203 approx) would look like:

```xml
<stack name="StatelessBeanTimeoutMethodStack">
    <!--  Include the common timeout method stack
        After JBAS-8130, just use this stack-ref and remove the 4 duplicate listed interceptor-refs
        below 
    <stack-ref name="TimeoutMethodStack"/> -->

    <interceptor-ref name="org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.EJB3TCCLInterceptor"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="org.jboss.aspects.currentinvocation.CurrentInvocationInterceptor"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="org.jboss.ejb3.BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor"/>

    <!--  The additional SLSB specific ones -->
    <interceptor-ref name="org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="org.jboss.ejb3.security.RunAsSecurityInterceptorFactory"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="CMTTx"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="org.jboss.ejb3.tx.BMTTxInterceptorFactory"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor"/>
</stack>
```

Same problem occurs with MDB's.

Se also: [RunAs does not work on EJB timer bean timeout methods](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBPAPP-7685)

Comment: Thank you, but the modification does not seem to have any effect. I will test more deeply.